# Storing Objects in blob datatype in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, data-structures, blob

I am trying to store images in BLOB datatype in mysql but mysql has four blob types with different size ranges :

```
tinyblob (0-255)
blob (0-65535)
mediumblob (0-1GB)
longblob approx (2GB or 4GB)
```

now I have sample images of various sizes stored in a zip file. I am keeping the list of byte[] of contents. I want to choose image that fit the definition of that blob range. I do not know the blob range before hand. 
How can I maintain the images so that I will get right size image every time when I call getImage(long length);?
I need some data strcuture suggestion.

Comment: a blob is a string representing an image, so, you know how bigger your images will be? if no, do you have permissions to resize /limit size of image files when user upload them?

Comment: I do not want to resize. I want to select an image based on size limitation among given images. I need an efficient way to process images

Comment: sorry, I cant get what you mean...

Comment: like I have image of size image1=9.6 kb, image2=5.2mb, image3=53 kb, image4=250 bytes. image1 can be assigned to mediumblob and longblob
image2 can be assigned to mediumblob and longblob, image3 can be assigned to blob, mediumblob and longblob and image4 can be assigned to  all blob types. now how to  organize these images so if I call getImage (65535) it will return one among image3 or image4

Comment: but, where the images come from? are icons and resources? or users can upload and store in database?

Comment: user can upload a zip file which can contain images of various sizes.

Comment: Store them all in longblob and use another column to store their size. Now you can easily filter any size-ranges.